# C++/Eigen: Get type of matrix argument to a template written for MatrixBase

Tags: c++, templates, types, eigen

I would like to create a template that takes an Eigen matrix as input and that includes a Cholesky decomposition (`LLT` in Eigen; see [doc](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/classEigen_1_1LLT.html#details)) in its body.

```
template <typename Derived>
double function_with_llt(const MatrixBase<Derived>& m) {
    LLT<m_type> llt_of_input(m); //how do I get m's type?
return 0;
}
```

The problem is that I need type of the matrix `m` to declare `LLT`. Substituting `m_type` with `MatrixBase<Derived>` did not work. I could use one of Eigen's dynamic matrix classes (e.g. MatrixXd) for LLT, but I would prefer to have decomposition matrices with fixed dimensions in later computations. Is there some `typedef` or other trick that could fix this?

Comment: It looks like you could use `auto llt_of_input = m.llt();` to avoid the issue, but I don't know enough about eigen to know exactly what type `LLT` wants for its template parameter.  Maybe `MatrixBase<Derived>::PlainObject`?

Comment: Just to confirm that Miles Budnek's comment is the right answer.

Comment: @Miles Budnek @ggael Thanks for your responses! I tried replacing `<m_type>` with `<MatrixBase<Derived>::PlainObject>`, I get an error:  type/value mismatch at argument 1 in template parameter list for ‘template<class MatrixType, int UpLo> class Eigen::LLT’
     LLT<MatrixBase<Derived>::PlainObject> llt_of_input(M);

Comment: @AliceSchwarze You need `LLT<typename MatrixBase<Derived>::PlainObject>` since `PlainObject` is dependent on a template parameter.  One of C++'s little gotchas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would take the matrix type as a template parameter:

```
template <typename MatrixType>
double function_with_llt(const MatrixType& m) {
    LLT<MatrixType> llt_of_input(m);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This will fail, if you pass, e.g., a `.block(...)` or a `Map(...)`